# hide the google maps api key for github

Tags: google-maps, github, gitignore, api-key

I'm following a tutorial for google maps v3 where in the `<head>` they include:

```
<script type="text/javascript"
      src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=API_KEY&sensor=SET_TO_TRUE_OR_FALSE">
</script>
```

I want to share my code on github but I don't want my API_KEY to be public. Is there something I can do with .gitignore to reference the above script but not share my api key?

Comment: Just see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72842869/9944300

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe it's easier if you just don't use a key. It's an optional feature so Google can track your API usage for example if you need to purchase additional quota.

Comment: yeah if it's not necessary no problem

Comment: The key is now required.