# Android map not displaying

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to display google map in Android ,i have map API even map is not showing and also not throwing any error.
I have use following 
**Java code**

```
public class GoogleMapActivity extends MapActivity {
    private Location myLocation;
    protected MapView myMapView = null;
    protected LocationManager myLocationManager = null;
    protected MapController mapController;
    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;

    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        this.myMapView = new MapView(this, "0jzIB6m5R1kLa_rGte-DS9PhF3KlSgqYHUZognA");    
        this.setContentView(myMapView);
        myMapView.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
        myMapView.setSatellite(true);
        mapController = myMapView.getController();
        mapOverlays = myMapView.getOverlays();
        this.myLocation = new Location("gps");
        this.myLocation.setLongitude(77.52436144125092);
        this.myLocation.setLatitude(13.05096452223662);
        updateView();
    }

    private void updateView() {
        Double lat = myLocation.getLatitude();
        Double lng = myLocation.getLongitude();
        GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint(lat.intValue(), lng.intValue());
        mapController.setCenter(point);
    }
}
```

**Manifest**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.googlemap"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_GPS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

    <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name" >
        <activity
            android:name=".GoogleMapActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <uses-library android:name="com.google.android.maps" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Finally i get output blank. please have a look at below screen

[image]

on please suggest me where i'm  wrong

Comment: Are you using your own Map API key? If no, [Get the new map api key here](https://developers.google.com/android/maps-api-signup)

Comment: Yeah it's my own Api key

Comment: most likely connection problem if not missing API key

Comment: try this one - `setContentView(myMapView);` before `updateView()`

Comment: What your device or emulator shows?

Comment: Ah,wait. Is that your MapView shows blank, or even the MapView is not being showed?

Comment: emulator showing blank(i mean without map) please have l look o this https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-2JTsN6x-kG4/T-lpeQJK-PI/AAAAAAAAAbw/zyl3oVGdWG0/s514/GoogleMap.png

Comment: did set your emulator with google api ?

Comment: Try to get new Map Api key. It seems you're using old key

Comment: Which type of key you have debug or release.

Comment: new Map Api key and for degug key if using on emulator..

Comment: change Windows > Preferences > Android > Build, change the location of the debug keystore instead of the one you generated for your app.

Comment: You should Sign your Application using Release Key instead of debug keystore.. If you use release key then map will be shown in all the Devices else if you use debug key Map View will shown only on that particular machine in which you developed your App [Sign using Release Key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7444392/google-maps-key/7445030#7445030)

Comment: Also ensure that you have copied your key into XML without any spaces.. Better copy from browser to notepad then copy& paste to XML

Comment: Did you get your output?

Comment: your code is working in my test applicatoin , just change Google Map API key. for testing purpose you have to use your debug.keystore for getting API key.

Comment: Its not working Don't know why i'm using this API Key 0XFb5vkYPZnmTTyD8qQbhNm5tX5ARy6k9tSw3fw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have not added myMapView in current layout ...........

you created in java code

```
this.myMapView = new MapView(this,
                "0jzIB6m5R1kLa_rGte-DS9PhF3KlSgqYHUZognA");
```

but looks not added in any layout.. as per [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517833/mapactivity-set-apikey-programmatically)

1. If you dynamically create the MapView via its constructor, you can
   supply the API key that way from Java code, but then you will need to
   dynamically add it to your layout.
2. You cannot both have the widget in your layout and set the API key
   in Java.

Solutions :

- option 1 - Create  a Linear layout in for XML and add the myMapView
  in that.
- option 2  -Create  Map view in XML it self and get that by
  findViewById.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3517833/mapactivity-set-apikey-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

Try placing the mapview on the layout xml with its api key there as well and then on the activity just get a reference of the map and continue normally.

main.xml with mapView:

```
    <com.google.android.maps.MapView android:id="@+id/mapView"
     android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:enabled="true"
     android:layout_centerInParent="true" android:clickable="true" android:apiKey="YOUR MAP KEY"/>
```

Activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
mapView = (MapView)findViewById(R.id.mapView);
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code which has working fine for me -

```
public class MapTabView extends MapActivity 
{

    MapView map;

    String api = "02gY92RWvQgV-k5CUQvGPowJkw8HkN4Tmm-HDIQ";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle icicle) 
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        map = new MapView(this, api);
        map.setClickable(true);
        map.setEnabled(true);
        setContentView(map);
    }
    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem menu_item)
    {
        switch (menu_item.getItemId()) {
        case R.id.satelite:
            map.setSatellite(true);
            map.setTraffic(false);
            break;

        case R.id.traffic:
            map.setTraffic(true);
            map.setSatellite(false);
            break;

        default:
            break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

Have a look at this [TabMapsExample](http://www.ziddu.com/download/19766021/TabMapsExample.zip.html)